# Наследование в c#(unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Только начала углубляться в ООП, не понимаю в чем ошибка. Ругается на base. Изначально метод OnCollisionEnter2D был и там, и там (внутри был одинаковый конструктор) и все работало, так что ошибка тут точно в наследовании, может его тут вообще нельзя...

```
public class Spike : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject == Player.Instance.gameObject)
        {
            Player.Instance.GetDamage();
        }
    }
}

public class Saw : Spike
{
   
    public float speed = 0.04f;


    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        : base(collision){ }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать ключевое слово base как для вызова конструктора базового класса. Для вызова родительского метода нужно использовать другой подход с простым обращением `public void OnCollisionEnter2D(int collision) { base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision); }` или `public void OnCollisionEnter2D(int collision) => base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision); `

Comment: Действительно заработало(только не int collision, а Collision2D collision). Но выдает предупреждение 
**"Saw.OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)" скрывает наследуемый член "Spike.OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)". Если скрытие было намеренным, используйте ключевое слово new.**                                                                                                                                   Можете подсказать что исправить, чтобы компилятор все устраивало?

Comment: Spike -> public virtual void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) // Saw-> public override void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)

Comment: Да, забыл обратно вернуть int на Collision2D т.к. предварительно проверял не в unity, что ругаться не будет. Предупреждение убирается добавление new как подсказывает IDE `public new void OnCollisionEnter2D( ...`